# Javascript dropdown menu to change HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add some interactive controls to this: http://jakscoproductions.com/2520dip8/

Here's the code specifically: 
HTML

```
        Zoom:
        <select id="zoom" onchange="zoom()">
            <option>50%</option>
            <option>75%</option>
            <option selected="selected">100%</option>
            <option>125%</option>
            <option>150%</option>
            <option>200%</option>
        </select>
    Opacity: 
        <select id="opacity" onchange="opak()"> 
            <option value="0.3">30%</option>
            <option value="0.55">55%</option>
            <option value="0.7">70%</option>
            <option value="0.85" selected="selected">85%</option>
            <option value="0.9">90%</option>
            <option value="0.99">99%</option>
        </select>
```

JS

```
//zoom
function zoom()
{
var zooM=document.getElementById("zoom");
document.getElementById("bbtop").style.width="zooM.options[zooM.selectedIndex]";
document.getElementById("bg").style.width="zooM.options[zooM.selectedIndex]";
}
//opacity
function opak()
{
var opak=document.getElementById("opacity");
var element = document.getElementById('bbtop');
element.style.opacity = "opak.options[opak.selectedIndex]";
element.style.filter  = "opak.options[opak.selectedIndex]";
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're setting width / opacity / filter with those exact strings :  `"zooM.options[zooM.selectedIndex]"`, `"opak.options[opak.selectedIndex]"`

Comment: Ok... so I would make it not do that by taking off the quotation marks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the string literal and assign the `text` (or `value`) property of the selected option as below.

```
//zoom
function zoom()
{
   var zooM=document.getElementById("zoom");
   document.getElementById("bbtop").style.width= zooM.options[zooM.selectedIndex].text;
   document.getElementById("bg").style.width= zooM.options[zooM.selectedIndex].text;
}
//opacity
function opak()
{
   var opak=document.getElementById("opacity");
   var element = document.getElementById('bbtop');
   element.style.opacity = opak.options[opak.selectedIndex].text;
   element.style.filter  = opak.options[opak.selectedIndex].text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
element.style.opacity = "opak.options[opak.selectedIndex]";
```

This line will set the string as style. use value returned by above line instead.

use
`element.style.opacity = opak.options[opak.selectedIndex];` instead

Answer (score 0):

This one is correct :

```
//zoom
function zoom() {
  var zooM=document.getElementById("zoom");
  document.getElementById("bbtop").style.height=zooM.options[zooM.selectedIndex].value;
  document.getElementById("bg").style.height=zooM.options[zooM.selectedIndex].value;
}

//opacity
function opak() {
  var opak=document.getElementById("opacity");
  var element = document.getElementById("bg");

  var opacityValue = opak.options[opak.selectedIndex].value;

  element.style.opacity = opacityValue;
  element.style.filter  = "alpha(opacity=" + opacityValue * 100 + ")";
}
```

**Edit** : please note I assumed you want to set the opacity of the `#bg` element, as there is no image in the `#bbtop` element.